# Zabbix 5 SNMP Discovery DELL IDRAC NIC

Tags: snmp, zabbix

I have some troubles with monitoring my DELL IDRACs NIC, I'm monitoring in my Nagios (old plataform) using MIB, now I migrate to Zabbix but auto discovery from Zabbix Template doesn't get all my NICs, just get bond0 interface that doesn't exist in my IDRAC.

For example:

```
[operador@SERVER1 ~]$ snmpwalk -v 2c -c cmnvtname 10.10.1.10 IF-MIB::ifDescr
IF-MIB::ifDescr.1 = STRING: lo
IF-MIB::ifDescr.6 = STRING: bond0
```

But if I call snmpwalk using my OID or MIB I get my NICs:

```
[operador@SERVER1 ~]$ snmpwalk -v 2c -c cmnvtname 10.10.1.10 1.3.6.1.4.1.674.10892.5.4.1100.90.1.30.1
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.674.10892.5.4.1100.90.1.30.1.1 = STRING: "NIC.Integrated.1-1-1"
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.674.10892.5.4.1100.90.1.30.1.2 = STRING: "NIC.Integrated.1-2-1"
```

I tried to change my SNMP OID to:

```
discovery[{#IFOPERSTATUS},1.3.6.1.4.1.674.10892.5.4.1100.90.1.3.1,{#IFADMINSTATUS},1.3.6.1.4.1.674.10892.5.4.1100.90.1.4.1,{#IFNAME},1.3.6.1.4.1.674.10892.5.4.1100.90.1.30.1]
```

Default value is:

```
discovery[{#IFOPERSTATUS},1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.8,{#IFADMINSTATUS},1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.7,{#IFALIAS},1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.18,{#IFNAME},1.3.6.1.2.1.31.1.1.1.1,{#IFDESCR},1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.2,{#IFTYPE},1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.3]
```

Some one know how I can solve it? In discovery doesn't show any error, but item doesn't create at all.

In Item Prototype I create item like:

```
Name: Interface {#IFNAME}: Operational status
Key: net.if.status[networkDeviceStatus.1.{#SNMPINDEX}]
SNMP OID: 1.3.6.1.4.1.674.10892.5.4.1100.90.1.3.1.{#SNMPINDEX}
```